# CiviCRM Home Menu Blank - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, menu, civicrm-home

Thank you for looking at my question.

I am a Drupal and Civi newbie.

When I installed CiviCRM the CiviCRM menu appears in the menu bar however, there are no dropdowns. When I click on it the page appears blank and the "configure your dashboard button does nothing". The pages are there when I type in the url but the links dont show up in the menu.

[image]

[image]

I have:

Uninstalled and reinstalled,
Cleared caches,
Confirmed the site/default folder is writable,
Confirmed CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL,
Moved menu to Management--Admin,
Disabled and re-enabled,
Installed the Admin Menu module.

How do I get the menu to appear properly?

Thank you for your help.

P.S. received this error also which may be related to menus: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/modules/system/system.module on line 2134

UPDATE

Heres the debugging console text: imgur.com/a/nEcTD

```
civicrm?reset=1:46 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://beta.myblackmarket.uk/civicrm?reset=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,400italic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
civicrm?reset=1:50 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://beta.myblackmarket.uk/civicrm?reset=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:900'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
yM1bINZq:7 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
civicrm:447 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
civicrm:699 Uncaught TypeError: CRM.$ is not a function
webform_civicrm_forms.js:403 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
civicrm?reset=1:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://beta.myblackmarket.uk/civicrm?reset=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: There is system status error. Just click on that link, you will get more information.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a Javascript error - please check out this guide to [troubleshooting Javascript errors in CiviCRM](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).  Feel free to update the question with more info if this gets you further to a solution.

Also - that fatal error sounds like it's related to Drupal core.  I'd fix that before trying to get CiviCRM working - it's much harder to fix a system broken in two places than one!

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your help. As I said Im a bit of a newbie and was able to follow part of the link. Heres a screenshot of my console with the errors in it. I am not sure what they mean or how to resolve it. http://imgur.com/a/nEcTD

Comment: @MrDLister Please update your question with the link, and also copy/paste the text so others can search on it?

Comment: The mixed content error indicates that you've got a site encrypted with SSL (aka "HTTPS"), but that you're loading data from other sites over an unencrypted connection - notably, Google fonts and maps.  I would look at whatever Drupal extensions you're using that load fonts and maps and find the option to load them over HTTPS.

Comment: @MrDLister - thanks for the text update!  That actually made me see the errors below the mixed content errors, which are more likely to be the cause.  It looks like your Javascript isn't loading.  Please a) check your paths (**Administer menu » System Settings » Directories** and **Administer menu » System Settings » Resource URLs**).  Also please check the "Network" tab in your browser's developer tools - are there any 404 errors, particularly on Javascript files?

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your response. I don't see any 404s and I'm not sure what I'm looking for in the suggested locations but there doesn't appear to be anything out of place there? http://imgur.com/a/r9ral